# the firebase reference is not being added

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

for some reason, the data is not being added to the firebase database. maybe its because i set the database in test mode? i have no idea. this was working before, however today it stopped working.

```
    private EditText EditTextFullName, EditTextAge, EditTextEmail, EditTextPassword;


    private TextView registerUser;


    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();


            EditTextFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fullName);
            EditTextAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
            EditTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
            EditTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);



            registerUser= (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerUser);
            registerUser.setOnClickListener(this);

            
    }






    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()){
                    case R.id.registerUser:
                            registerUser();
                            break;

            }
    }

    private void registerUser() {
            String email = EditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String age = EditTextAge.getText().toString().trim();
            String fullname = EditTextFullName.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = EditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();




            if(password.length() < 6) {
                    EditTextPassword.setError("Min password length should be 6 characters");
                    EditTextPassword.requestFocus();
                    return;
            }


            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {




            if(task.isSuccessful()){

                    User user = new User(fullname, age, email);
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                            .child((FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid())
                            .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {




                    if(task.isSuccessful())

                                    {
                                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "User has been registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            startActivity(new Intent(Register.this,Login.class));

                                    } else

                                    {
                                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Failed to register", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                            };
            });
                    }


  }
  });

    }
}
```

Comment: "it stopped working" is really hard to help with. If you set a breakpoint on `if(task.isSuccessful())` and run in the debugger, does it reach that line? If so, if you step through the code from there, what branches does it go into?

Comment: I set a breakpoint and ran the debug but honestly i don't understand what is going on. The debug wouldnt allow me to step into the line of code that i set the breakpoint on. “ E/ple.carguyzmai: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000” this was highlighted in red though

Comment: {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",  
    ".write": "true", 
  }
}


These are my rules in the database btw.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i did the debug with a breakpoint. i then clicked step-in and it took me to zzw.class. it also gave me a notif saying "source code does not match the byte code".

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out that I completely flopped when writing my code. Turns out in my User class with my constructers, i had my strings there twice causing the database to not know what to use.